# MySQL for admin and user(receptionist)

Tags: mysql

I am doing a project on hotel management, How can i create a MySQL database (that will connect to java), where the admin has the sole right and the receptionist has privileges on some of the tables, like inserting, selecting...

Comment: There is a lot of documentation out there about how to set up security and privileges on MySQL.

Comment: See how privilages work here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: I am on windows7, I already set up a login page for admin? How can i do it on application level (using java)?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html. However, I would highly recommend to handle these kind of permissions on application (java) level, so you don't have to switch mysql users inside your app.

Comment: +1. managing the permission/privileges can be done at the application level, without having multiple database users. If there are two separate applications, then each can use a different database connection, and different database users.

Comment: Okay, I only did setup login page for the admin, it;s just connected to the dbase, so how do i grant permissions at the application level(using java) bearing in mind that the receptionist should also insert, update the dbase

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL.

```
mysqladmin -u root password "secret-password"



mysql -u root -p'secret_password'

> CREATE DATABASE hm ; 

> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON hm.* TO hm_receptionist@'%'
>  IDENTIFIED BY 'secret_password' ;

> GRANT ALL ON hm.* TO hm_admin@'%'
>  IDENTIFIED BY 'secret_password' ;
```

Comment: I will try this, but others are talking about granting permission at the app,ication level (using java), I have never tried that before

Comment: @user2576896 - i upvoted the answer from Glenn Vandamme. The way we do our applications is for the application to get one set of database privileges, and its within the application that the authorization happens, as to whether a particular user is permitted to run a particular transaction or not.  If you have two separate applications, then they can have different logins with different sets of privileges. My answer was directed at the question you asked.